# Ellipord Filter Design Attenuation

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to design a filter with a `passband` between `0` and `0.25pi` using an elliptic filter order selection.

The parameters it specifies are between `0` and `1` exclusive.

I've tried using a small number `(10^(-5))` as a substitute but I get ripples near `0`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Just use `ellipord` and `ellip` functions in matlab:

```
   x  = randn(500,1);    
   [n,Wp] = ellipord([100 500]/2000*2,[90 510]/2000*2,0.1,60);
   [b,a] = ellip(n,0.1,60,Wp);
```

This obtains a 11th order filter, implemented as:

```
   y=filter(b,a,x);
   fvtool(b,a,'Fs',2000);
   plot([x y]);
```

[image: Elliptic Filter Freq. Response]

This is an elliptic passband filter between 100Hz and 500Hz, with sampling frequency of 2000Hz. I've set a bandpass ripple of just 0.1dB, and a huge 60dB of bandstop. Of course a zero ripple is impossible in a elliptical filter, unless you use another filter structure (just like a `butter`).

Have fun.